# I cannot solve the "Install these packages without verification" problem

Tags: installation, apt, package-management, source

I Googled and Googled and I just cannot find a solution to this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install <whatever>
```

Gives me:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
```

and

```
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

I cannot find a decent solution.

The closest I got was to run:

```
sudo apt-get install debian-keyring debian-archive-keyring
```

But then, even thought, and against my good judgment I agreed to install the package without confirmation, I get:

(I replaced http with XXXX because of forum limitations).

```
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err XXXX://il.archive.ubuntu.com gutsy/universe debian-archive-keyring 2007.02.19-0.1
  404 Not Found
Err XXXX://il.archive.ubuntu.com gutsy/universe debian-keyring 2005.05.28
  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch XXXX://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2007.02.19-0.1_all.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch XXXX://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/debian-keyring/debian-keyring_2005.05.28_all.deb  404 Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Trying to run `apt-get update` also does not help:
I get tons of "404 Not Found" errors.

Can someone please direct me to a good solution to this problem?

I cannot understand why this issue is not better documented.

There must be a simple solution which allows me to update my list of sources or whatever.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? I see some references to gutsy in there, which is 7.10 - 4 years old!

Comment: Caesium: You are right. And I will indeed upgrade since it seems to be simpler then solving this issue. And yet there should be a solution I think.

Comment: I think you may even struggle to update, since some of the intermediate versions between gutsy and oneiric will no longer be available from the repositories. There's a couple of Questions floating about on this issue too. My advice would be start over if you can ;)

Comment: @Caesium The old versions should be available to get (using apt) at old-releases.ubuntu.com

Comment: @Azendale: Does it means that if I change my sources list to old-releases.ubuntu.com I can install software from there?

This is just a theoretical question though. I will fresh-install modern version.

Comment: @YonatanOrlev I believe so, but it would not be updated. (That's what end of life means).

Comment: @Azendale Yeah, but you could in theory upgrade through them one by one and eventually be at the current version, which will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade an End of Life release, look at the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades page. From that page they have links to each version jump.

You are most likely getting the error you are because apt can no longer find package lists (which are missing because they are no longer on the server which is because you are on a EOL release.) All the packages for old releases have been moved to old-releases.ubuntu.com when they reached their end of official support from Canonical.

While you could probably change your /etc/apt/sources.list to using the old release servers, you should just upgrade (be it through all the steps or through backing up your data and reinstalling) so that you get the latest security fixes and better support.